# How do I connect text fields from child window?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a single-window (OSX, not iOS) app that works beautifully, but I need to add a Preferences window. I have created the window and linked it to the Preferences menu (to which it opens and displays as expected). However, now I need to interact with the text fields I have set up.

Here is my new window:
[Settings.xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAecw.png)

Here is my main window:
[MainMenu.xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q9HJ.png)

Again, I can display it just fine, but I need to be able to set the values of the text fields in the Settings window. Not real sure how to do that? I am trying to stay away from Storyboards at the moment (just trying to keep it simple; maybe phase II). I am storing the values from the `Settings` window in the Keychain (which works beautifully in `MainMenu.xib`). Now I just need to be able to enter them and save them from `Settings.xib`.

My file structure is pretty straightforward. I have `AppDelegate.swift` which is doing all of the work. Do I (and how do I) connect `Settings.xib` to `AppDelegate`? I know I can bind the text fields from `Settings.xib` to outlets in `AppDelegate` (but when I do that I get an error: [General] [<NSApplication 0x6080001005a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accountNumber).

I know this is a `n00b` question, but it is so simple it is hard to find an applicable answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend writing a window controller for the settings. It will have its own nib file and wiring up the fields will be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @johnelemans. Took me a bit to figure out how to do that, but that was it. Works like a champ. Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new window controller was the key. My problem, as I stated in my question, was getting the text fields wired up as functional outlets. I was able to show the window as desired, just couldn't get to the text fields.

I created `SettingsWindowController.swift` to subclass `NSWindowController`. My connections are as shown:

[Window connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohSIe.png)

[File's Owner connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T224h.png)

Additionally, in `Settings.xib`, the `Custom Class` of `File's Owner` is set to `SettingsWindowController`. Then the individual text fields are connected to `SettingsWindowController.swift` as outlets.

In `SettingsWindowController.swift`:

```
`import Cocoa

class SettingsController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var accountNumber: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var meterNumber: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var webCredentialKey: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var webCredentialPassword: NSTextField!

    // allows window creation without needing to specify NIB name
    override var windowNibName: String! {
        return "Settings"
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // initialization code removed for brevity
    }

    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        // teardown code removed for brevity

        NSApplication.shared().stopModal()
    }
}'
```

In `AppDelegate.swift`,

```
`var prefs: SettingsController? = nil

@IBAction func OpenPreferences(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        NSApplication.shared().runModal(for: (self.prefs?.window)!)
    })
}`

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    prefs = SettingsController()
}`
```

Hope this helps someone else.